# How can I deserailize JSON to an inputbean using objectmapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON String as below:

```
{
  "PhoneNumber": "0000000000",
  "cart":
  [
     {
       "Number": "1234",
       "realm": "2345",
       "id": "1234",
       "quantity": "1"
     }
  ],
  "employeeId": "345",
  "group": "10080",
  "empEmail": "xyz@gmail.com",
}
```

How can I deserailize to an `inputbean` using `objectmapper`?

```
inputBean = objectMapper.readValue(json.toString(), inputBean.getClass());
```

I am getting error like

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] 
out of START_OBJECT token\n at
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, what's the trailing comma for?

Answer (score 4):

What is the class of inputBean?

To deserialise that JSON you'll need the following beans:

```
class InputBean {
    String phoneNumber;
    List<Cart> cart;
    String employeeId;
    String group;
    String empEmail;
    // Getters, setters and constructor omitted for brevity
}

class Cart {
    String number;
    String realm;
    String id;
    String quantity;
    // Getters, setters and constructor omitted for brevity
}
```

You then deserialise it with:

```
InputBean inputBean = objectmapper.readValue(json.toString(), InputBean.class);
```

You should also take a look at your JSON source material because it's inconsistent in property naming with some properties beginning with an uppercase character and some with a lowercase character.

Comment: I removed the trailing coma and now i am able to read but i am getting cartlist as { ,Number, 1234,realm,2345,id,1234,quantity,1,} with size as 10. Which is wrong and unable to map it to input bean. How can i get the dictionary for the cart.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your problem is now. Can you update your original post with what you've got right now and any exception/error you're getting?